# What's the purpose of Lock()/Unlock() calls when firing COM events?

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, com, atl

A typical piece of code firing events in an ATL COM server goes like this (copied from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21129187/57428) and trimmed a bit):

```
HRESULT Fire_MessageTrigger()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    T * pThis = static_cast<T *>(this);
    int count = m_vec.GetSize();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        pThis->Lock(); // I'm asking about this...
        CComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(i);
        pThis->Unlock(); // and this

        IDispatch* pConnection = static_cast<IDispatch *>(punkConnection.p);
        if (pConnection == 0)
            continue;

        DISPPARAMS params = { NULL, NULL, 0, 0 };
        hr = pConnection->Invoke(2, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT,
            DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, 0, NULL, NULL);
    }
    return hr;
}
```

What's the purpose of the `Lock()` and `Unlock()` calls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is thread safety measure around `m_vec` member variable (list of sinks).

You can have the following being executed on a concurrent thread:

```
template <class T, const IID* piid, class CDV>
STDMETHODIMP IConnectionPointImpl<T, piid, CDV>::Advise(
    _Inout_ IUnknown* pUnkSink,
    _Out_ DWORD* pdwCookie)
{
// ...
        pT->Lock();
        *pdwCookie = m_vec.Add(p); // <<--- Modifying m_vec here
        hRes = (*pdwCookie != NULL) ? S_OK : CONNECT_E_ADVISELIMIT;
        pT->Unlock();
```

Your next question would be why they are not locking a few lines above around accessing `m_vec.GetSize();`.

This is the way they did it: they are OK to miss an individual event delivery in case of concurrent vector access, as long as it does not create memory corruption or otherwise undefined behavior. After all, the subscribing call could happen a moment later and miss this event anyways. The same applies to the case of unsubscription from events (`Unadvise`).

The priority here is to lock as rare as possible, and then unlock as soon as possible. Note that sink call takes place while unlocked, and sink list can take a modification while we're iterating through the list of sinks making calls on them.

UPD. Visual Studio 2008 always generates `Lock`/`Unlock` pair. So do newer versions. From 
"\VC\VCWizards\CodeWiz\ATL\ImplementInterface\HTML\1033\default.htm" file:

```
strProxyMethod +=
    "\t\tfor (int iConnection = 0; iConnection < cConnections; iConnection++)\r\n"+
    "\t\t{\r\n"+
    "\t\t\tpThis->Lock();\r\n"+
    "\t\t\tCComPtr<IUnknown> punkConnection = m_vec.GetAt(iConnection);\r\n"+
    "\t\t\tpThis->Unlock();\r\n\r\n";
```

Earlier VS versions could generate lock-free code and the code is only updated when you re-generate proxy class manually from VS IDE.

Comment: Okay, I've also seen similar code that does not `Lock()`/`Unlock()`. Would it be correct to say that if the server should support concurrency then all event firing code should `Lock()`/`Unlock()` the current object?

Comment: It's all about thread safety. Sometimes you need locking, sometimes you don't. At all times you are interested to hold locked state the minimal possible time. Also note that with STA base (`CComSingleThreadModel`) these calls resolve to empty method and generate no  code.

Comment: Suppose I have ten COM classes with the same threading model other than Main STA and each supports some events and they are all implemented using `IConnectionPointImpl`. Will I need such locking in all of them?

Comment: Perhaps you want to provide a more specific example for your last question. Because these `Lock`/`Unlock`s protect access to `m_vec` member (of this instance! regardless from how many classes and instances you have on the project) and then in another scenario we might be talking about rather a different thing.

Comment: Well, I understand that. Suppose I have ten classes... (as in the comment above) - would it make sense to have this locking only in some of them but not in others?

Comment: Why would you want to remove this locking at all? This locking is not necessary if you otherwise ensure where is no sink advise/unadvise while events are being fired. If you guarantee this, you can remove the locks and nothing bad is going to happen. Otherwise `Fire_` method might be accessing sink list while you are modifying it on another thread, and result is something like memory access violation on call on bad COM pointer.

Comment: I wouldn't remove it for fun, the problem is I see ten classes... (yeap) and some of them have this code and some of them don't and there're no comments anywhere around.

Comment: There could be a bug in older versions of VS which generated lock-free code. I am pretty sure there were other bugs with these sink lists there too, in case of multiple sinks, so bug explanation is quite real. Maybe you can re-generate files that have no locks, to see if current VS version adds them.

Comment: Jeez-marie, what do you have to do to get a helpful vote around here?

Comment: @HansPassant: presumably an [tag:atl]-tag visitor, who is a rare guy nowadays?